# Help needed finding a closed form or approximation for an integral(hypergeometric function)

Tags: integration, hypergeometric-function

I am seeking (preferably) a closed form for the integral

\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln\left[x(1-x)\right]}{\sqrt{x(1-x)(1-zx)}} dx, \;\;\; z<1
\end{equation}
I know from previous work that

\begin{equation}
B(b,c-b)\,_2F_1(a,b;c;z) = \int_0^1 x^{b-1} (1-x)^{c-b-1}(1-zx)^{-a} \, dx
\end{equation}
so I am hoping that my integral will be some other form of a hypergeometric function.  I have tried expressing the logarithm as a hypergeometric function using the relationship $\ln(1-z)=-zF(1,1;2;z)$ and using properties in the book "Higher Transcendental Functions."  I have also scoured nist.gov and "Table of integrals, series, and products." for some kind of useful identity but I cant find anything.  The closest thing I found is equation 7.512.9 from Table of Integrals Series and Products, which is a result for

\begin{equation}
\int_0^{1}x^{\gamma-1}(1-x)^{\rho-1}(1-zx)^{-\sigma}F(\alpha,\beta;\gamma;x)dx
\end{equation}

which I wont type because my integral doesn't conform.

At this point, an approximation would be fine.  But if someone can see a way to solve this thing analytically, that would be amazing.  Either way, I appreciate the help!

Comment: Incidentally, if you're looking for an estimate as $z \to 1$ or as $z \to -\infty$, or there's some other domain of $z$ that you're particularly interested in, you should say so. A more narrow problem like that may be much easier to answer.

Comment: In my problem, $z=\frac{\theta-1}{\theta}$ where $\theta>0$.  So I am interested in a solution for $z<1$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Formula for $\int_0^\infty \frac{\log(1+x^2)}{\sqrt{(a^2+x^2)(b^2+x^2)}}dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/710537/formula-for-int-0-infty-frac-log1x2-sqrta2x2b2x2dx)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A closed form for $\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln(x+4)}{\sqrt{x\,(x+3)\,(x+4)}}dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/550585/a-closed-form-for-int-0-infty-frac-lnx4-sqrtx-x3-x4dx)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Integral $\int_0^1\frac{\ln\left(x+\sqrt2\right)}{\sqrt{2-x}\,\sqrt{1-x}\,\sqrt{\vphantom{1}x}}\mathrm dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/570997/integral-int-01-frac-ln-leftx-sqrt2-right-sqrt2-x-sqrt1-x-sqrt)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$ B\left( T+\tfrac{1}{2},\tfrac{3}{2}\right)\cdot {}_2 F_1\left(\tfrac{1}{2},T+\tfrac{1}{2};T+2,z\right)  =  \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^T}{\sqrt{x(1-x)(1-xz)}}\,dx$$
hence by differentiating both sides with respect to $T$, then evaluating at $T=0$ we get that
$$ -\tfrac{\pi}{2}\left(1+2\log 2\right)\cdot {}_2 F_1\left(\tfrac{1}{2},\tfrac{1}{2};2,z\right)+\tfrac{1}{2}\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{\Gamma\left(n+\tfrac{1}{2}\right)^2\left[1+2\log 2+H_{n-1/2}-H_n\right]}{n!\Gamma(n+2)}\, z^n $$
exactly equals $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log x}{\sqrt{x(1-x)(1-xz)}}\,dx$, and $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log(1-x)}{\sqrt{x(1-x)(1-xz)}}\,dx$ has an analogous closed form.
 The previous line can be simplified as follows:
$$\frac{\pi}{2}\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{\binom{2n}{n}^2}{16^n(n+1)}\left[H_{n-1/2}-H_n\right] z^n $$
and this is not, strictly speaking, a hypergeometric function, but it is pretty simple to approximate such object with hypergeometric functions by considering the asymptotic expansion of $H_{n-1/2}-H_n$. Campbell has shown that similar series has closed forms for many specific values of $z$, and together with Sondow [we proved](https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.03221) that Fourier-Legendre series expansions provide a very effective technique for evaluating $\int K(x)g(x)\,dx$. The above series is an instance: at $z=1$ we have
$$\frac{\pi}{2}\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{\binom{2n}{n}^2}{16^n(n+1)}\left[H_{n-1/2}-H_n\right] =\color{red}{2\pi-4}. $$

Comment: Thank you for this very elegant solution. I am working through the details(its not trivial to me as I am not a mathematician). I am wondering: 

1) Is the equation you began with written somewhere? I did not see it referenced anywhere I looked. 
2) I am also having a hard time with the second term in the derivative of the LHS of the provided equation. 

Additionally, I browsed your arXiv page and it seems like you do work with this function. Would you suggest a reference or two which would have a comprehensive list of identities and relationships? Thank you!

Comment: 1) The initial equation of this answer is just the second equation of your question, with a suitable choice of parameters 2) the second equation in my answer depends on the derivatives of Pochhammer symbols / Beta functions, i.e. on the $\psi$ function. For some insights on similar series, which turn to be natural generalization of Euler Beta function, have a look at the work of *John Campbell*.

Comment: Thank you on 2), I will look into that.

re: 1), $b=T+1/2$ but $c-b-1=-1/2$ would mean $c=T+1$ not $T+2$ though right?

Comment: @JohnSnyder: it looks like I manipulated something more complex than the wanted integral, you are right. Indeed $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log x}{\sqrt{x}(1-x)}\,dx = -\frac{\pi^2}{2}\neq 2\pi-4$. Luckily, the shown techniques applies also if $T+2$ is replaced by $T+1$, and they lead to a hypergeometric series with a "harmonic twist" anyway. So the provided references still applies.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I posted a followup question to this one [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2498309/ratio-of-hypergeometric-function-with-a-harmonic-twist-to-a-hypergeometric-fun)

Answer (score 1):

Not an approximation but an upper bound for the integral

$$
\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln\left[x(1-x)\right]}{\sqrt{x(1-x)(1-zx)}} dx\leq \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln\left[1/4\right]}{\sqrt{x(1-x)(1-zx)}}$$
$$=\ln 8\dfrac{F\left[\sqrt{1-z},\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{1-z}}\right]-F\left[1,\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{1-z}}\right]}{\sqrt{z-1}}
$$

In which the following elliptic function was used:
$$F(z,k)=\int_{0}^{z}\dfrac{du}{\sqrt{1-u^2}\sqrt{1-k^2u^2}}.$$

Comment: You can get a tighter ub using $x(1-x) \leq \frac{1}{4}$

Comment: @Jon_simon: Don't know how I came up with $1/2$ I actually wanted to have $1/4$ :D.