# Ratio of hypergeometric function with a "Harmonic twist" to a hypergeometric function

Tags: calculus, summation, gamma-function, hypergeometric-function, digamma-function

Continuing with a problem I am working which involves the work [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2495033/help-needed-finding-a-closed-form-or-approximation-for-an-integralhypergeometri), I am faced with the following expression.

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2\,_2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2};1;z\right)}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)_n\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)_n}{\left(1\right)_n}\frac{z^n}{n!}\left[H_{n-1/2} - 2H_n\right]
\end{equation}
where  $H_{n-1/2}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2}{2k-1}$ and $H_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}$.

I recognize that the series is *almost* a hypergeometric series, but I would like to approximate this expression to obtain a function of $z$.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is logarithmic derivative of ${}_2F_1(a/2,1/2;a;z)$ with respect to $a$ at $a=1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first: $\phantom{}_2 F_1\left(\tfrac{1}{2},\tfrac{1}{2};1;m\right)=\tfrac{2}{\pi}\,K(m)$ and the complete elliptic integral of the first kind is very simple to approximate through the AGM mean (see Borwein et al.). It just remains to estimate

$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{\binom{2n}{n}^2 z^n}{16^n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\frac{2}{2k-1}-\frac{1}{k}\right)=2\log 2\,K(z)+\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{\binom{2n}{n}^2 z^n}{16^n}\left(-2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{t^{2n}}{1+t}\,dt\right) $$
which equals
$$ 2\log 2\,K(z)-2\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{\binom{2n}{n}^2 (zt^2)^n}{16^n}\cdot\frac{dt}{1+t}=2\log 2\,K(z)-\frac{4}{\pi}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{K(zt^2)}{1+t}\,dt$$
or
$$ 2\log 2\,K(z)-\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{z}\frac{K(t)}{t+\sqrt{tz}}\,dt $$
and plenty of accurate approximations for $K(t)$ (for $t$ in a right neighbourhood of the origin) [are known](http://www.exstrom.com/math/elliptic/ellipint.html), so the numerical evaluation of the given "monster" is actually pretty simple with the right tools. $$\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{\binom{2n}{n}^2 z^n}{16^n}H_n$$
can be managed in a similar way.

Comment: At the risk of asking a low level question, why is
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\frac{2}{2k-1} - \frac{1}{k}\right) = -2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{t^{2n}}{1+t}dt?
\end{equation}
In an effort to understand I have evaluated them numerically in software as well as tried to manipulate the integral representations of harmonic series and I am not seeing it.  Additionally, my term is $H_{n-1/2} - 2H_n$, would that change things or can the same technique be used?  Thanks for your time.

Comment: I cannot seem to verify the above equality analytically or numerically for $H_{n-1/2} - H_{n}$ or my quantity of $H_{n-1/2} - 2H_{n}$.  Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: $$\frac{t^{2n}}{1+t}=\frac{t^{2n}-t^{2n+1}}{1-t^2}$$ expand $\frac{1}{1-t^2}$ as a geometric series and perform termwise integration.

Comment: There is a little typo, however. We have $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\frac{2}{2k-1}-\frac{1}{k}\right)=H_{n-1/2}-H_n+2\log 2 = 2\log 2-2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{t^{2n}}{1+t}\,dt $$

Comment: Thank you, I will keep working through this.  Additionally, in the first line of your initial answer, I believe you meant $\phantom{}_2 F_1\left(\tfrac{1}{2},\tfrac{1}{2};1;m^2\right)=\tfrac{2}{\pi}\,K(m)$

Comment: @JohnSnyder: that is just a notation issue. I used $K(m)$ meaning that $m$ is the elliptic modulus (Mathematica's notation) and not the elliptic parameter.

Comment: I am revisiting this and am having some trouble so [I posted a followup to this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2626980/hypergeometric-series-with-harmonic-factor)