# Hypergeometric series with harmonic factor

Tags: calculus, summation, hypergeometric-function, harmonic-numbers

I am following up on [a post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2498309/ratio-of-hypergeometric-function-with-a-harmonic-twist-to-a-hypergeometric-fun) I made a couple months ago as I am revisiting this problem.  I desire a way to approximate the sum

$$\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{\binom{2n}{n}^2 z^n}{16^n}H_n$$

for a specified value of $z$.  So far, I have tried noting that

$$H_n = \int_0^1 \frac{1-t^n}{1-t} dt$$ and distributing the terms of the sum into the integral and working with the hypergeometric function.  However I am having trouble proceeding from there.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why would you need an approximation when this sum has a closed form in terms of elliptic integrals? see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2613728/generating-function-of-the-sequence-binom2nn3h-n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Mathematica's notation (where the argument of the complete elliptic integral of the first kind $K(x)$ is regarded as the elliptic *modulus*) we have 
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{\binom{2n}{n}^2}{16^n}\,u^n = \frac{2}{\pi}\,K(u)\tag{1}$$
hence it is simple to check that
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{\binom{2n}{n}^2 H_n}{16^n}\,z^n =\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{K(zu)-K(z)}{u-1}\,du\tag{2}$$
and the integral in the RHS of $(2)$ can be numerically approximated with arbitrary precision by exploiting the relation between $K$ and the $\text{AGM}$ mean. For instance, $K(x)\approx \frac{\pi}{1+\sqrt{1-x}}$ or $K(x)\approx\frac{\pi}{2(1-x)^{1/4}}$. Similar series [appear](https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.03221) in the computation of $\int_{0}^{1}K(x)\log(1-x)\,dx$ and $\int_{0}^{1}E(x)\log(1-x)\,dx$ through Fourier-Legendre series expansions.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, this is roughly where I left it at, except I wrote it in terms of hyper geometric functions.

To be more specific.  I am essentially looking for some simple function that can approximate this for z as $z\rightarrow 1^-$.

For example.  I know that for a hypergeometric function $_2F_1(a,b;a+b,z)$, $\lim_{z\rightarrow 1} \frac{_2F_1(a,b;a+b,z)}{-log(1-z)} = c$.  Do you think its possible to come up with anything that could do that for the RHS in (2)?

Comment: @JohnSnyder: you are already done, since $$ K(x) = \tfrac{\pi}{2}\cdot\phantom{}_2 F_1\left(\tfrac{1}{2},\tfrac{1}{2},1,x\right).$$ With extra accuracy, in a left neighbourhood of $x=1$ we have $$ K(x)\approx \frac{5}{2}\log(2)-\frac{1}{2}\log(1-x^2).$$

Comment: but I can't do anything with $K(zu)$ term, right?  Since even if $z\rightarrow 1^-$, $u\in(0,1)$?

Comment: But you can still write the RHS of $(2)$ as $$\iint_{(0,1)^2}  z\cdot K'(z(u-1)y+z)\,dy\,du. $$

Comment: I looked it up so I am not 100% sure but just to be clear, $K'(k) = K(\sqrt{1-k^2})$?

Comment: @JohnSnyder: no, in the previous line $K'(x)$ simply stands for $\frac{d}{dx}K(x)$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72417/discussion-between-john-snyder-and-jack-daurizio).

Comment: I don't quite follow, can your double integral be used to infer about the behavior of the RHS of $(2)$ in a left neighborhood of $z=1$?

Alternatively, I was thinking that with respect to $u$, the integrand in the RHS of $(2)$ would be well behaved for $u \in (0,1-\varepsilon)$, right?  Therefore, I could determine the behavior of the RHS of $(2)$ by splitting up the integral into $u \in (0,1-\varepsilon)$ and $u \in (1-\varepsilon,1)$ and using the limiting behavior of $K(z)$ or $_2F_1(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2};1;z)$ for the second part.

Is this reasonable?

Thanks.