# Closed form of series involving harmonic numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, euler-sums

> I need a closed form of the sum $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{((n-1)!)^2(H_{2n}-H_{n-1})}{(2n)!} $$
> where $H_n$ denotes the Harmonic number and "!" is the factorial notation.

I tried: Harmonic number has the integral representation [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/353691/harmonic-number)
$$H_n=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1-x^n}{1-x} dx $$
Denote $$S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{((n-1)!)^2(H_{2n}-H_{n-1})}{(2n)!} $$
So we obtain $$S= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{((n-1)!)^2}{(2n)!}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1-x^{2n}}{1-x}dx-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{((n-1)!)^2}{(2n)!}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1-x^{n-1}}{1-x}dx$$
Interchanging the order of summation and integration (which I am supposing and has to be proved later) we get $$S= \int_{0}^{1}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(\Gamma(n))^2}{\Gamma(2n+1)}\left(\frac{1-x^{2n}}{1-x}\right) dx-\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(\Gamma(n))^2}{\Gamma(2n+1)}\left(\frac{1-x^{n-1}}{1-x}\right) dx$$
Now we have [see here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum+%28%28Gamma%28n%29%29%5E2%281-x%5E%282n%29%29%29%2F%28Gamma%282n%2B1%29%29%2C+n%3D1+to+infinity)
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(\Gamma(n))^2}{\Gamma(2n+1)}\left(\frac{1-x^{2n}}{1-x}\right)=\frac{\pi^2-36(\arcsin(\frac{x}{2}))^2}{18(1-x)} $$
Also we have [see here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum+%28Gamma%28n%29%5E2+%281-x%5E%28n-1%29%29%29%2FGamma%282n%2B1%29%2C+n%3D1+to+infinity)
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(\Gamma(n))^2}{\Gamma(2n+1)}\left(\frac{1-x^{n-1}}{1-x}\right)=\frac{\pi^2\ x-36(\arcsin(\frac{\sqrt{x}}{2}))^2}{18x(1-x)} $$
So we have by above two equations $$S=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\pi^2-36(\arcsin(\frac{x}{2}))^2}{18(1-x)} dx-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\pi^2\ x-36(\arcsin(\frac{\sqrt{x}}{2}))^2}{18x(1-x)}dx$$
I request some guidance and help for this question. Thank you!

Comment: Note that your sum is$$\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{H_{2n}-H_{n-1}}{n^2 \binom{2n}n}.$$A similar sum is evaluated [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3306742/infinite-series-sum-n-1-infty-frac4nh-nn22n-choose-n) so perhaps the methods demonstrated there may be of some use.

Comment: @user170231 Thanks a lot for the link. It would be really helpful if you could write a closed form of the sum as an answer.

Comment: There are a lot of methods (both *ad hoc* and systematic) to show this sum is $2\zeta(3)/3$.

Comment: @pisco Thank you. Please write as an answer about any one method.

Comment: It may be a derivative of a hypergeometric function like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4640487/evaluation-of-int-01-frac-log-x-dx-sqrtx1-x1-cx/4641076#4641076). Also, $y=\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt x}2\right)$ may help